# Problem using Firebird with VS2008 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, firebird

Good morning, i'm trying to import the DLL of the Firebird.Client to use with the VS2008 but everytime i add the reference to the dll i get the message:

```
Warning 1   The referenced component 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient' could not be found.
```

I've tryied to add the reference path to the project, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Is there anything else i can do?

Thanks in advance

Link to where i've download cliente:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/2.6.5/NETProvider-2.6.5.zip/download

Comment: add link from where you downloaded client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, to use Firebird with VS2008 i had to use a older version of the Firebird client, that worked just fine. Awsome? Not that much, but if you have no choice like me you can try it too, just use:

Version 2.5.2 for .NET 3.5/2.0 with Entity Framework support

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when I received a new Windows 7 workstation -- it seems to affect Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.  Everything worked fine in VS2008 on my old Windows XP machine.  Unfortunately the ultimate solution for me was to migrate everything to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: But VS2008 doesn't work with Net CF 3.5 for Windows Mobile 6. It just works with windows 7 mobile. And there's another problem, i have a huge project for windows mobile 6 that many corporations still use, and they don't plan to change their smartphones that early.